# Graph based instead of stack based

Tags: functional-programming

I wonder about the idea of representing and executing programs using graphs. Some kind of stackless model where the each node in the graph represents a function and the edges represent arguments to the functions. In this way a function doesn't return the result to its caller,but passes the result as an arg to another function node. Total nonsense?  Or maybe it is just a state machine in disguise? Any actual implementations of this anywhere?

Comment: Something like an Abstract Syntax Tree?

Comment: No. Not a tree. A graph. A real graph

Comment: Step 1: Pick a good functional programming language.  Step 2: Make a graphical UI to define it.  Seriously, this whole technique strikes me as being a frontend for an existing language, or as one of those "beginner" programming languages you occasionally see that work via visually defining the function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a [State machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Comment: Right. But doesn't anything is just a state machine ?

Comment: I didn't notice your comment, "maybe it is just a state machine in disguise" comment in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think Dybvig's dissertation [Three Implementation Models for Scheme](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.66.786&rep=rep1&type=pdf) does this with Scheme.

I'm pretty sure the first model is graph-based in the way you mean. I don't remember whether the third model is or not. I don't think I got all the way through the dissertation.

Answer (score 0):

for javascript you might want to checkout [node-red](http://nodered.org) (visual) or [jsonflow](https://npmjs.org/package/jsonflow) (json)